# Get all files with a revision greater than 1 in a perforce workspace

Tags: perforce

I want to get all files that have revision greater than 1 in a specific workspace, how can I do that in perforce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files with a revision greater than one are not necessarily modified in a particular workspace. They could have been modified anywhere, then got submitted and thus have a new revision.
If you still want a list of all files in your current workspace with rev > 1 do this:

```
p4 have | grep -v "#1"
```

If you want to list the files that are open (e.g. opened for modification) in your current workspace do this:

```
p4 opened
```

Comment: Your solution with "grep" is perfect for what I asked (you will win the answer flag :) )
Now I noticed another problem. I want to discover all changed files after the first commit (all files changed after change list 1), because there are some files that I added before the first commit and were not changed (they have revision 1).

Comment: I probably got you wrong, but isn't it the same as in your original question? (e.g. all files with revision greater than 1)

Comment: All files changed after changelist 1 (i.e. changelist 2 or later) that are synced to the current client:

 p4 files @2,#have

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it doesn't account for files that have "#1" in the filename.  It also doesn't account for files that latest commit is the 10th-19th, 100-199th etc.   That could be fixed by adding a space after the 1

Answer (score 0):

To find all files modified **by** a workspace, a useful command is p4 changes: http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/p4_changes.html